# Why does my call to winapi GetWindowPlacement fail (using JNA)?

Tags: java, winapi, jna

These are the winapi methods

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowPlacement(
  _In_       HWND            hWnd,
  _In_ const WINDOWPLACEMENT *lpwndpl
);
typedef struct tagWINDOWPLACEMENT {
  UINT  length;
  UINT  flags;
  UINT  showCmd;
  POINT ptMinPosition;
  POINT ptMaxPosition;
  RECT  rcNormalPosition;
} WINDOWPLACEMENT, *PWINDOWPLACEMENT, *LPWINDOWPLACEMENT;
```

My Java code:-

```
class WINDOWPLACEMENT{
   public int length;
   public int flags;
   public int showCmd;
   public POINT    ptMinPosition;
   public POINT    ptMaxPosition;
   public RECT     rcNormalPosition;
}
WINDOWPLACEMENT wind = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowPlacement(hwndLSM, wind);
```

The error is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument type jna.extra.WINDOWPLACEMENT at parameter 1 of function GetWindowPlacement

How to use GetWindowPlacement/SetWindowPlacement with JNA?

Comment: Include your definition of `java.extra.WINDOWPLACEMENT`.  Most likely you forgot to extend `com.sun.jna.Structure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.extra.WINDOWPLACEMENT` must extend `com.sun.jna.Structure` and properly implement `getFieldOrder()`.

**EDIT**

Setting length in the constructor, and `getFieldOrder()` definition:

```
public class WINDOWPLACEMENT extends Structure {
    public WINDOWPLACEMENT() {
        this.length = size();
    }
    public List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("length", "flags", "showCmd", "ptMinPosition", "ptMaxPosition", "rcNormalPosition");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How to set length while declaring `WINDOWPLACEMENT` WINDOWPLACEMENT i = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();