# Interact with Windows windows programmatically

Tags: windows, api, window

I wonder if there is any way to somehow interact with windows that are currently open on a Windows system. I am interested in getting some of their properties, namely:

- Location
- Dimension
- is in background?
- possibly window title

Preferably, I would like to do that in Java but any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: See: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091531/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-of-a-program-window-in-java) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067484/get-titles-of-non-java-windows-in-java) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312793/why-does-my-call-to-winapi-getwindowplacement-fail-using-jna)

Answer (score 1):

[A comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017220/interact-with-windows-windows-programatically#comment63477242_38017220) by theB linked to good resources for Java. I'll run through the relevant Windows APIs, in case you want to go native with C++.

To enumerate all the top-level windows in the system, use [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx). You give it a callback function with the signature of [`EnumWindowsProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633498(v=vs.85).aspx), so it will receive each window handle as the first parameter.

You can get the window location (in screen coordinates) and dimensions with the [`GetWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Pass in the window handle you received and get an `LPRECT` (pointer to [`RECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx)) out.

To determine whether a window is maximized, use [`GetWindowPlacement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518(v=vs.85).aspx) and check the `showCmd` field of the [`WINDOWPLACEMENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632611(v=vs.85).aspx) structure you receive.

Finally, to get a window's caption, use [`GetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx). (As an aside, if you want to get the text of a control in another process, you'll need to send the [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627(v=vs.85).aspx) message yourself.)